# Windows 10 - black screen on boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, black-screen-of-death

After trying several times since the last couple months, I managed to install a Windows 10 update on my existing Windows 7, using an install image (I had an issue with default boot not being set up for Windows hard drive).

However, now I only get a black screen on boot. Not even a cursor.
I have a multi monitor configuration, primary monitor seems to be getting some input, but won't show anything but black screen.

I've tried several things - change primary video card in BIOS, change cables, monitors... Even pulling out the main card completely, and relying on the internal one. Always the same black screen. In case I get the black screen, both monitors show in their menu they get a valid input (native resolution, 60Hz).

I can get to command prompt, via recovery options, but not safe mode or low resolution mode.
Accessing ntbtlog.txt shows many "did not load driver" lines, including nVidia.

I have an nVidia 650Ti Boost for the main card, and i5 3570k with integrated GPU and motherboard output for the secondary.